# How does the polycrystalline structure of graphite produce the circular rings in electron diffraction experiment?

Tags: diffraction

When one performs the electron diffraction experiment to measure the lattice spacing of a polycrystalline graphite one gets the following pattern:

[image]

My lab manual and other online sources give the reason that since the sample is polycrystalline the set of planes for a particular incident angle can be randomly oriented as the bonds become the layers of graphite are weak so all the possible orientations are possible and hence for a particular angle a circle is traced on the screen.

The above seems to be just a vague picture and I am not able to imagine (visualize or draw on paper) how this would happen.

Also, would the pattern simply be alternating patches for a moncrystalline crystal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right, a monocrystalline solid will produce a characteristic set of bright spots with a distinctive symmetry pattern that depends on the angle between the principal axes of the crystal arrangement and the incoming X-ray beam.

Now imagine that that same crystal has been hit with a hammer and fractured into many tiny crystals. The X-ray beam is still coming in at the same angle relative to the glob of fractured crystallites, but because their orientation is random, those bright patches produced by each turn into *rings* with characteristic radii, with the ring centers on the central axis of the X-ray beam.

Comment: Those different fractured crystallites may have the planes make an angle different from the first crystallite right? Also, what does a characteristic plane mean? I guess for Graphite $d_{100}$ and $d_{111}$ are characteristic planes. Surely other planes also diffract right (or do they) ?

Comment: suggest you consult a materials science text that contains a section on the *powder camera technique*.

Comment: Okay, thanks. Do you know why there are outer and inner rings instead of a single sharp ring line? Is it because my incident electron beam also has a finite radius of cross-section or is it because of something else (like uncertainty in something and something)?

Comment: Each individual diffraction spot which would have been present in a single-crystal test is rotated into a ring in a powder test. A sample of polycrystalline hydrated aluminum oxide will, for example, have many discernable rings with different radii and intensities. I found this out when I did a powder camera X-ray test on the corrosion products produced when my apartment mates left the cast aluminum cookware in the sink for multiple days at a time, causing severe intergranular pitting corrosion in them. This served as my senior project in my corrosion science class in 1975!!

Answer (score 0):

This is a fantastic experiment, one that my physics juniors perform each fall in our Experiments in Modern Physics course.  Your question is one that perplexed me for some time when I first performed this electron diffraction measurement.  I highly recommend Leighton's "Principles of Modern Physics" textbook, especially the chapter on X-rays (from which this answer derives).  Much of what physicists know about electron diffraction was derived from earlier work on X-ray diffraction that revealed the inner structure of solids that have a repeating unit cell.  Samples such as the graphite used in the TEL.2555 (https://physicsx.erau.edu/Courses/CoursesS2023/PS315/Electron%20Diffraction/TEL2555_2.pdf) are polycrystalline, as you noted. This means there are small domains or grains that internally posses the single-crystal structure, but the many grains are randomly oriented within the bulk material. The layer of graphite deposited on this nickel mesh target is only a few molecular layers thick.  Leighton's description bolstered my understanding of the geometry: Every unique set of three non-collinear atoms in the crystal can be intersected by a characteristic plane.  For hexagonal graphite, there are two unique characteristic planes responsible for producing the smaller and larger rings in your image.  The smaller ring results from electron reflection off the set of planes with the larger ($d_{10}$ = 0.213 nm) spacing, and the larger ring off the set of planes with the smaller ($d_{11}$ = 0.123 nm) spacing. Diffraction patterns always follow this inverse relationship: angles to regular features in the pattern increase when the aperture is decreased. I have not found a great diagram to illustrate the importance of the distribution of azimuthal or axial angle (often called $\phi$) of the many polycrystalline grains, but this is responsible for the continuous ring of constructive interference locations, rather than the single point that would result from a single crystal target.  All points on a given ring share a common angle $2\theta$ measured from the beam axis, where theta is defined as in Bragg's Law: $2 d_{jkl} \sin\theta = m \lambda$.  I again urge a careful reading of Leighton's and other textbooks (especially the section on Electron Waves in Tipler's "Foundations of Modern Physics") on X-ray diffraction and crystal structure to find good diagrams that will lead to your better understanding of this phenomenon. Cheers!